# AIR application throttled when nothing to render

Tags: apache-flex, air

I'm dabbling with an AIR application that is trying to receive and process data over a socket. I've found that its framerate is drastically cut after somewhere between 40 and 120 seconds of being inactive (by which I mean, the window is not the focused window). I'd like to avoid that throttling.

The target framerate is unchanged throughout the life of the application. Both `backgroundFrameRate` and `frameRate` are set to 24 and do not change. When this throttling occurs, the actual framerate of the application changes to about 0.1 fps (although it various slightly and occasionally).
[image: 0.1 fps with 10,039 ms waiting for next frame]

The framerate immediately recovers if I activate the window (for example, by clicking on it).
[image: high fps again]

I never see this problem--even if the application is inactive--if something is visibly happening in the window; if I set a Timer to change a label's text every second, the throttling never occurs. If I cover up the label, the throttling reoccurs.

Is the throttling really the result of not having anything to render? If so, is there another way to avoid this throttling that won't require that the window remain visible?

Comment: I'm doing this on an OSX machine with 10.9.1. If that becomes relevant, I will add that tag.

Comment: Have you considered and tried the 'Frame rate Throttler' to be found if you research that as it handles this type of items very well! I have used this code many times before. I'm not quiet sure why you are using 24 does your App. need to have that set high? I used 7 to 12 very satisfactory! regards aktell

Comment: @aktell A frame rate throttler appears to affect whether the application reduces its frame rate when the application deactivates. Unless I'm missing something, the throttler is ineffective because the _runtime itself_ reduces the frame rate of the application after some period of inactivity.

Comment: This is the default behavior of AIR to save power and CPU cycles.  On mobile, it drops to 4fps as soon as the app loses focus. On desktop, it depends on what is being run, I believe. Additionally, OS X, as of 10.8, limits what apps can do in the background by limiting their processing power (although I believe this only occurs in certain apps). What is the reason you need it to remain at normal framerates when inactive?

Comment: The application acts as a facade for running a particular function. Because it was convenient, I set up the AIR app to act as a server. I need it to get a normal (or at least decent) framerate when it is inactive because I'd like it to be able to handle quite a few requests per second periodically.

Comment: @JoshJanusch Regarding the limitations to save power and CPU cycles: if there's no way around it, that sounds like an answer. If you could link to some documentation (that isn't about backgroundFramerate) on the AIR behavior and some other documentation on OS X, I'd choose it as an answer.